# Linux Server user copy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-management, copy

Is there a way to copy user list (with data and passwords) from one server to another.

We have two servers and one of those is new. I need to create same users (that exist in `/home/`) and set same passwords (if possible) sure `/home/` dir will be copied also for the configs.

To be specific its Ubuntu server 10.04.1.

`Linux <name> 2.6.18-238.5.1.iv.028stab085.3 <time> i686 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the files you would usually need to copy:

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/shadow
/etc/group
/etc/gshadow
/home/$USER
/var/mail/$USER
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
```

Comment: What about other users (www-data or ftp)? Won't the ID's mix up?

Comment: @JackLeo - if the servers are both Ubuntu, then the system accounts should all have the same IDs (if they didn't, upgrades wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to copy /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and /etc/group along with the home directories

Comment: You forgot at least about mail spools and cron tabs.

Comment: Also forgot gshadow. While group passwords are rarely used anymore, some tools will throw errors if group and gshadow are out of sync.